# NLog, UWP - write logs to System.Diagnostic.Debug

Tags: c#, uwp, nlog

How to configure NLog in UWP project to show logs in Visual Studio Window:Output?

Note that in UWP apps `Console.WriteLine("hello")` doesn't work.

To write in VisualStudio Window:Output you have to use `Debug.WriteLine("hello")` from `System.Diagnostic`.

I use below (almost default) NLog config.
Log to file works nice. Log to console doesn't work.

```
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

var storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") { FileName = storageFolder.Path + @"\file.txt" };
var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");

config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole);
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);

NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Comment: Yes UWP doesn't like console.But you can try `OutputDebugString`. See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/OutputDebugString-target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP won't support console.

You could write to the [Trace target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Trace-target). This will use the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` - which is almost the same as `System.Diagnostics.Debug` - both are visible in Visual Studio.

```
var traceTarget = new NLog.Targets.TraceTarget("target1");
```

Comment: Great tnx!!! BTW: 1/ I had to add `traceTarget.RawWrite = true` otherwise logs had strange prefix. 2/ `OutputDebugString` also works.